# How can I seed only my test-database without specifying additional arguments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, mysql2, seeding

Is there a way to configure [seed_fu](https://github.com/mbleigh/seed-fu) so that it seeds **only** my test-database? I know there is a way to specify environment like [this](https://www.mobomo.com/2008/04/seed-fu-simple-seed-data-for-rails/):

```
rake db:seed RAILS_ENV=test
```

but is there a way to confugre seed_fu to use test-environment as default so that I don't need to specify it all the time?

Comment: `rake -T` describes seed_fu-command like this: `rake db:seed_fu                         # Loads seed data for the current environment`. I am working in `development` environment by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your seed_fu task you can set the environment explicitly:

```
Rails.env = 'test'
```

To accomplish what you need, I'd wrap the seed_fu task like this:

```
namespace :db do
  task :custom_seed => :environment do
    Rails.env = 'test'
    Rake::Task["db:seed_fu"].execute
  end
end
```

Then just call:

```
rake db:custom_seed
```

Comment: Under `seed_fu task` you mean my seed-file for example? If that's the case then I understand that I should specify `Rails.env`  in every seed-file separately- is there a way to do it in one place?

Comment: Nice approach! Tested it and works fine. But is it possible to define environment to `test` under the same `seed_fu` command? I'd like to avoid situation where my fellow-collegues accidentally seed the dev-base because they don't know there is a new specific command for seeding **only** the test-base. 
I tried to add a new rake task with exactly the same name but of course it resulted in `stack level too deep` error because at the end I want to call original seed_fu command with `Rake::Task["db:seed_fu"].execute`.

Comment: Yes, you'll get a recursion like that. I think the only way is to rename the existing seed_fu task and then define your own. Its a bit messy, but I think doable: http://lslezak.blogspot.co.at/2009/06/renaming-rake-task.html

Answer (score 0):

I found that by placing fixtures inside environment-specific subdirectories like

```
/lib/fixtures/test
/lib/fixtures/development
/lib/fixtures/production
```

eliminates the possibility that wrong fixtures would be activated in wrong environment, which is also one of my main problems. Still- **environment has to be specified when running seed_fu** in this variant too. It just eliminates the possibility of running wrong fixtures in wrong environment.

Fixtures placed right under `lib/fixtures` will **always** be run- looks like a place for general fixtures that you want to preserve in all environments.

For more information look for seed_fu gem [railtie file](https://github.com/mbleigh/seed-fu/blob/master/lib/seed-fu/railtie.rb#L7) and seed_fu gem  [rake task](https://github.com/mbleigh/seed-fu/blob/master/lib/tasks/seed_fu.rake#L33).

Answer (score 0):

Just discovered another approach by executing a command in a subshell:

```
namespace :db do

  desc "Seed_fu only in test-database"
  task seed_fu_test: :environment do
    system("rake db:seed_fu RAILS_ENV=test")
  end

end
```